# Change spacing above and below chapter

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I have following document:

```
\documentclass[final]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter One}
\lipsum{1-5}
\end{document}
```

and I want to be able to modify spacing above and below chapter heading. Let's say I want to set both to ugly setting like 0pt.

As you can see from MWE, my first thought was to use `titlesec` package to do it. But in [`titlesec` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) there is following note:

> **Notes.** `\titlespacing` does not work with either `\chapter` and `\part` unless you change its title format as well by means of
>   `\titleformat`, the simple settings, or `\titleclass`.

Now I am bit confused whether it is possible to manipulate chapter headings spacing with `titlesec` package. If yes, how? If not, what are other options to achieve that?

Comment: The duplicate question answers the `titlese` part *and* gives you some alternatives ;-)

Comment: Please do not close a question after 45 min. Give the OP time to react, for example to say: "Yes it is a duplicate" ...

Comment: @Johannes_B Somehow I did not find that other question while searching for an answer. It is indeed a duplicate and answers from other question solve my problem. Thanks :)